# How to update database according to the error message I get?

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, error-handling

I have a python script and a database. They are connected. The python script raises some errors when the inputs are wrong. For example, one of the functions is to count classes. If there are less than 2 classes, an OneClassError is raised and the program is killed. There are other customized errors like OneClassError.

There is a column in my database table called error_code. It should update according to the specific error I get. For instance, it should be 401 if it's OneClassError; it should be 402 if it's TestClassMsg. (I make up the error names here just for easier illustration.)

For now, I only know how to update that column by a single value. **I wonder how** to automate the process that there are 401 and 402 where I don't need to specify 401 or 402 - **the error_code identifies the error and knows the code for it.**

```
# here is my simplified example:

def count_class_sim(inp_data):
    """
    :param inp_data:  the path of the input data

    :return: pass or fail
    """
    unique_cc, count_cc = np.unique(inp_data[inp_data != 0], return_counts=True) 
    if len(unique_cc) < 2:
        raise OneClassError()
    else: 
        raise TestClassMsg()

data1 = np.array([0,0,1,2,3,3,4,5,5,5])
count_class_sim(data1) # ---- TestClassMsg: TestingTesting

data2 = np.array([0,0,1])
count_class_sim(data2) # ---- OneClassError: Data has only 1 non-zero class - rejected.
```

Here is my database connection code. Note that I only know how to give a single value to error_code. I want a sophisticated way to do that. **Can anyone show me how to modify the "set error_code = "command?**

```
try:
    count_class_sim(data2)
except:
    cur.execute("""update lc_2020 set error_code = 401 
                        where quad_id = '010059' """)
    conn.commit()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have custom error, you can mention your error code in custom error class itself.

Example:

```
class OneClassError(Exception):
    code = 401
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    #remaining logic 
    
try:
    #code that may cause Exception OneClassError
except OneClassError as e:
    print(e.code)
```

I hope I Understand your query and answered right, If any questions ask in comment section.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the input! I also did some search and adding a code seems to be the correct solution. But may I have a question for you? so actually what's running in try block is an automated script, the entire try-except is another script. Is it possible that the error code in the inner script can be understood by the outer script?

Comment: Are you saying try-except contains an autogenerated try-except block?. If that is a case and the exception is occuring in inner try block, it must be catch in the inner except block or else if except block is editable then you can raise an Exception again in inner except to catch that error in outer Exception.

Comment: If I given you a right answer. Just accept it. It will marked as solved [you can check here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)